# How instantiate a object property on demand in objective-c, in a generic way

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, lazy-loading

This is for a ORM.

I have a class `Invoice` that have a `Customer` property:

```
@interface Invoice : DbObject {
}

@property (nonatomic,strong) Customer *customer; //Customer is a DbObject
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger user;

@end
```

I have several instances of this. Now, how I can instantiate on demand a `DbObject` property with obj-c? I don't wanna to code each getter for all the cases, but do it in a generic way, like with python and overriding `def __getattr__(self, attr)`.

Comment: Well, your first problem is that have a class named `Document`, not `Invoice`...

Comment: A fix the code sample, thanks

Comment: Unclear.  Do you want to "lazy create" the object for a getter, or just have the getter automatically created?  The former requires (simple) code.  The latter you get for free (in the latest Xcode), just by coding the @property.

Comment: Is for lazy create the object. So for example, the customer=1, then when I access Invoice.customer it load a Customer object from the DB

Comment: Requires 5-10 lines of code per property (beyond setup for the object creation).  How many lines depends mainly on whether you want it to be threadsafe or not.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't wanna to code each getter for all the cases

So, what you're saying is, when a call like `anInvoice.customer` is made, your Invoice class should do something to provide the instance which is more or less a template - it works more or less the same way for `customer` and for `zingleberry`, in a way that can be worked out from the name.

The way to deal with something like this is not to implement the getter (and prevent it from being synthesized), and to allow `resolveInstanceMethod:` to be called. At that point you can generate the getter with `classAddMethod` through a templating method that behaves in accordance with the name of the method originally called.

Comment: It is easier to see than to explain: here's an example that does the sort of thing you're talking about: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk1ch12p370dynamic/ch12p342dynamic/ViewController.m (and see my book for further discussion of what's going on here)

Comment: Objective-C is amazing!

Comment: @user3125367 It's okay, but Ruby would be so much nicer in this situation.

Comment: Ok, I see the code but it have "setName", "setNumber", so look like is necessary to hardcode it. How can get SEL as a string so I can do it more dynamically?

Comment: @mamcx That would be a separate question (or, hey, you could just do a little research and discover `NSStringFromSelector` on your own).

Comment: Ok, but I still don't figure how ask for a specific object. For example, if Customer=123 in the DB, how pass that info to callValueForKey?

Comment: I've no idea. How were you going to get it from the database in any case? You know that we are being asked for `customer` - you take it from there. I don't know how _your_ app's data model works.

Comment: Ah, I meant, how I pass a parameter to the function template? class_addMethod must match the # of params (if I understand it correctly), so instead of getCustomer() is possible to route it to getCustomer(Id=123)?

Answer (score 0):

I really never used that and am curious whether it will work at all, but the reference manual even has some snippets for that. Please report back if it really works. This is very interesting.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/resolveInstanceMethod:

(Sorry, the `:` is not included into link by SO site engine, you have to append it manually or scroll down a little)

Comment: Not quite sure how this would help? He would still need to write the implementation for lazy fetching himself, surely?

Comment: @HenriNormak Yeah, once per base class, and a bit of hand-made introspection per subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want... but you can overwrite a getter to make it lazy.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) Customer *customer; // in .h

-(Customer *) customer // in .m
{
    if(! _customer) //or whatever ivar you are using
    {
         _customer = [Customer new]; // or whatever you do to create the customer from the DB
    }
    return _customer;
}
```

you can also specify a different name for the getter with:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong,getter=myCustomer) Customer *customer; // in .h
```

the default setter will still be created.

Comment: This is ok as a manual solution. I wonder is about a generic one.

Comment: well it depends on the [Customer new] line if you can do something that is the same for all types you can easily wrap in a function like macro.

Answer (score -2):

you dont need to create getter/setter for any object. Use can directly use them using
object.customer.

Comment: That will not instantiate the objects.